# How to Connect iPhone with external device?

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, external-accessory

I am currently working with printing functionality.

and printer is wireless.
my question is how i should connect with printer in ios ?

need to connect with bluetooth with device.

but bluetooth is not detecting device

is there any link ?
please help me integrate phone with device

Comment: What's the printer Make and Model?

Comment: No Airprint found when i search printers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model in question is not in the Apple's [AirPrint compatible device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201311) list and therefor will not work via AirPrint off the shelf.

Epson has an [app on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/epson-tm-utility/id726122574?mt=8) which has a wizard of setting up such devices either with WiFi or Bluetooth.

---

Important note though from [Epson](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supAdvice.jsp?UseCookie=yes&noteoid=279101&type=highlights):

> If you are developing an iOS App for an Epson MFi series POS printer with Bluetooth, it must be approved by Apple before it is made available in Apple's App Store or Apple's B2B App Store. This does not apply for iOS applications for printers with WiFi connectivity.

Comment: Really helpful.can you please explain about aproval by apple?

Comment: Just follow the information on Apple's Developers page (https://developer.apple.com/programs/)

Comment: cannot find partner.please check SSID and ip address. what to do

Comment: @KrutarthPatel unfortunately I don't have any experience with this software, sorry

Comment: You gave right solution.but my setup wizard of bluetooth or wifi not working

Comment: @KrutarthPatel need MFi means the transport method may be Bluetooth SPP.